# cURL Error #:Could not resolve host: - PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have problem with this code:

```
function get_request($url,$header_array){

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => $url,
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header_array,
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
          echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
          return $response;
        }

    }
```

I've got this error:

```
cURL Error #:Could not resolve host:
```

I know there are a lot of questions like this, but the answer from those questions didn't help me, because its different code. Does anyone can help me how to fix this error:

Comment: An empty or malformed URL is making it to your function. The error message should read `Could not resolve host: example.com`, but since no hostname is appearing in the message there is a problem with the URL supplied. Add `var_export($url, true);` to your error message.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things this could be; and generally its either a malformed URL or a networking issue outside the scope of cURL.

First, save yourself some time and just double and triple check you've typed the URL correctly. I do this time and time again =D

Next up, on the same machine and under the same user as your PHP code executes, run something like `curl -sS http://yoururl.com/example` from the command line. This will help you double check your code can actually make outbound HTTP requests.

If your curl command fails in bash, then you can look at a few causes depending on the errors:

- a networking issue (has your local/dev machine lost internet connectivity?)
- a firewall issue; is your firewall configured to allow inbound HTTP(s) and not outbound?
- is it a DNS issue (my favourite!). If the domain is new, perhaps it hasn't proposed to your server's upstream DNS yet.

At this point, your question turns from curl to networking and DNS so I don't dive deeper into debugging... but this is, at least, where I'd start in looking into your error message.

Comment: This does not happen when I visit only this certain page. But my scripts go through 3000 URLs and then this happens.  That means my code is good, i think so...

Comment: So, based on that specific url, whats the result of the suggested debugging tips above?

Comment: well, when I start only one certain URL script works great. the error happens when I start the full script. Then this error appears and not every time on the same URLs. If i start the script now, I need 24 hours to finish. This error will appear on some urls, and tomorrow it will be on the different ones.

Comment: I... subtly re-iterate my suggestion for debugging those that fail. Some logging/tracing might help your debugging too if you're awaiting on long running processes but thats beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: I checked all 3 options and didn't found nothing problematic

Answer (score 0):

reading the symptoms, it is possible the DNS resolver that you use is probably too busy (timeout) -or- limit the number of inquiry per IP address in a certain timespan. So, the same exact process will probably give a different error if run on a different day.

Comment: so are you suggesting that I sleep the script after every visit to the url?

Comment: another possible idea, you can round-robin different name server - so no admin will be upset and your script can run at full speed ;-)

Comment: how do you mean, do you have example?

Comment: this is what I suggest:

    x=0;
    mydns = [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, 1.1.1.1, ....]
    <loop> (all url)
         curl --dns-servers <mydns[x]> (url)
         ....
         ....
        x=x+1;
        if (x>10) x=0;
    </end loop>

If the number of error you are getting is 10%, it should be quite trivial say, alternating 10 nameservers  - it theoretically reduces 10% of the load. And if this is the cause, you shall eliminate your annoying error... give it a try

Comment: (sorry, new to this site, still cannot properly format the code)

Comment: Just remember one thing before going to bed: as a start, probably try to change the name server from Google notoriously congested 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4. Open DNS one or Cloudflare could be less congested.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact same problem, but I encapsulated my php curl commands into a class.  I tried increasing php memory limit, max execution time, reusing my curl class (rather than creating new instances), immediately close the curl connection, unsetting objects, changing api keys, etc... Everything and anything.  The thing that finally worked was calling the php function gc_collect_cycles() after about 100 curl requests.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php.  I think this points to inefficiencies within my scripts.  I hope this is still helpful.  You may also edit php.ini session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor.

Alternatively, setting `curl_setopt ($this->ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, TRUE);` works just as well.